# Cannot remove object from firebase database using Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular6

I have object of beers. Each beer have the following properties Brand, Country and image (passed as url). Here's firebase tree structure:

[image]

I'm trying to implement delete functionality in this way:

```
<ul id="ninja-listing">

  <li *ngFor="let beer of beers | filter:term">
    <div class="single-ninja">
      <span>{{beer.brand}} || {{beer.country}} || <img src="{{beer.imgUrl}}"></span>
      <div (click)="removeBeer(beer)">delete</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

removeBeer(key){
    firebase.database().ref('/').child('/bs-angular/'+key+'').remove();
  }
```

Any ideas would be appreciate Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the child node as child of your database, this doesn't work. Try this

`removeBeer(key){
    firebase.database().ref('bs-angular').child(key).remove();
 }`

P.S. Also you can simplify you work by using [Angularfire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2)

Comment: I get this error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "[object Object]". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"
    at Jr (firebase.js:1)
    at e.child (firebase.js:1)
    at